# swift - collection view didSelectItemAt doesn't work

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a problem with handling clicks on the colectionView item.
I work with xib files.

In ViewController I have:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate  {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          print("Click")

    }
}
```

Data source and delegate are connect with File's Owner.

Date source works, but delegate doesn't work.

What can I do to register clicking on a collection item?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: have you registered the Xnib?

Comment: @oyasumi  make sure there is no button over your xib view.

Comment: @Vasucd Thank you!!!, there was a button

Comment: @oyasumi  It happens :)